# Is there some way to get MathJax to display this complete equation nicely (and not into the margin)?

Tags: support, mathjax

In [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/34165/12102) I have a long equation. I've artificially broken it up into three terms t = A  (B + C) so it doesn't boggle the mind when transcribing.

However when I tried to display it completely, it runs off the right margin and into the hot network questions area.

I'm using MacOS and Chrome, is it just my browser, or is this actually the way it looks in other browsers as well? Is there some way to get MathJax to display this complete equation nicely?

> [image]

**UPDATE:**

Strangely I can not reproduce that screen shot!  By rescaling (shrinking) my browser horizontal window size I only get the line broken into several lines, sometimes with outside-the-margins extension to the right.

But I can't reproduce that all-in-one-line display I had earlier.

*How strange!*

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: I am not sure what is cause of this, but often I saw this behavior: Immediately after posting or after edit MathJax behaves in some way (with long formulas running out to the right). But if I refresh the page just after it, the way MathJax is shown changes. (And in most cases the problem with the right margin is no longer there.)

Comment: @Martin thank you for the verification; if I hadn't made the screenshot I'd assume I was seeing things... well, more things than usual.

Comment: dat ugly star in C (a2∗w2)

Comment: @Federico yikes! I've fixed that just now in the original; thanks!